# SQL developer connection password forgot

Tags: oracle

I am new here so I might not be able to give the exact detailed information about the problem but here we go.I had a connection made as system in sql developer.I forgot the password so I thought I could solve it by deleting it.But when I reinstalled it,the connection stays the same and didn't get deleted.Now I can't access the database or write any queries.
The error code is ORA-12505.

Tried reinstalling,Making new connection.
I am hoping to delete that connection and make a new one.

Comment: *The error code is ORA-12505.* This means that you use OracleDB and not MySQL. Edit the tags list.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-12505
> TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

You're not even getting *as far as* connecting to the database, so the password you enter is irrelevant.

Assuming you're using Pluggable Databases (PDBs) you need to set up Transparent Network Substrate (TNS) connectivity so that you get *into* the PDBs inside the Container Database (CDB).  Just connecting to the [Container] Database isn't any use to you, because you should rarely need to do *anything* in the CDB itself.

> I had a connection made **as system** in sql developer.

I would say that this is generally a Bad Idea.
Leave *all* the built-in Accounts well alone.

Create a Tablespace of your own, give yourself a Quota in that Tablespace (so you can actually store Data in it) then create an Account of your own, using that Tablespace as its default and grant that Account whatever privileges you need.  Then log out of sqlplus and [largely] forget all about SYSDBA.